# Way to query in salesforce about what data was changed by user, through SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

There are many objects in salesforce. Can i know what data was changed from user name. I tried searching on audit trail i can see that user has logged in, i want to know what was changed.

Any Query Like  `Select id from sobject ....where username=''`

Answer (score 1):

You can see records modified *most recently* by a specific user filtering on the `LastModifiedById` field:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedById = '...'
```

You can see records *ever* modified by a specific user by using a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) on the history table:

```
SELECT ID FROM MyObject__c WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT ParentId FROM MyObject__History WHERE CreatedById = '...'
)
```

Some caveats apply to this second approach:

- You have to enable Field History Tracking
- It will only tell you if the user ever modified any *tracked* fields (you're limited to 20)